# Angular 2 - Jquery | Adding styles (top/left) with a mouse position

Tags: css, dynamic, typescript, angular, styles

I'm looking for a way to add a div component in Angular 2 at a specific place (mouse event x/y).

https://jsfiddle.net/lennartquerter/w2c7uqw6/

```
this.xPos = xPos;
this.yPos = yPos;
```

i pass the position into my reject class, but i do not know how to make styles out of it ? I checked angular docs but i can only set booleans and fixed css values / classes. I would like to do something like this:

`[style]="rejectPosition"`

`this.rejectPosition = "left: " + this.xPos + "px ; top: " + this.yPos + "px;"`

But its not possible.
Is there a Angular 2 way to do this?

I found a way to do it without the reject Component, that just styles it inline with jQuery, but i do not like this approach.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
[style.left.px]="xPos" [style.top.px]="yPos"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: oh no ! i had to change it to style.top.px="reject.xPos" !

Comment: or [style.left.%] if you want to use percentage

Comment: I haven't tried but I guess all units like `em`, `vh`, ... are supported.

Comment: Hello, i have tried this. It is working in Chrome and firefox but not working in IE 11

Comment: I couldn't find anything about IE11 not supporting `style.left`. I assume there is some other incompatibility around that code that makes if not work in IE11. Try with the simplest possible example first to verify it is the style binding itself.

Comment: [style.top.%]="top" does not work for me at Angular 5.

Comment: What about `[style.top.%]="20"`? I doubt this is related to the `top` style setting. Either the value stored in `top` is not valid or the problem lies somewhere else.