# Setting element position in ngFor

Tags: angular

How can I set an element's left position to an iteree's value in a loop?

```
<div *ngFor="let label of labels" style="left: {{label.position}};">
  {{label.label}}
</div>
```

I've tried the braces but that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37372745/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38130705/3001761

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `[style]` binding:

```
<div *ngFor="let label of labels" [style.left.px]="label.position">
  {{label.label}}
</div>
```

Comment: Or just `style.left` if `.position` is e.g. `'10px'` rather than `10`.

Comment: @PierreDuc , could you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464889/to-get-a-reference-to-and-display-the-respective-current-positions-of-all-the-ng/57465251#57465251 , it is somewhat similar to the above, thanks