# To get a reference to and display the respective current positions of all the ngfor elements

Tags: angular

I want to get reference to each of the ngFor element and display there latest Top and Left position (these elements can be dragged that is why there positions will be changing)

I can get a value for single element but wrt to ngFor elements and there latest value , so when I try accessing it within ngAfterViewChecked() , I get the Querylist as empty

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
  {{item.text}}
  {{ topPos }}
</div>

@ViewChildren('elm') elm: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewChecked(){

  // for single
  let elempos = document.getElementById('toget').getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(elempos.top);
  topPos = elempos.top;

  //for ngfor elements
   console.log(this.elm.toArray());
}
```

Which lifecycle hook I should be using and how to display the latest current position of each of the element. Thanks!

[image]

I already have custom for calculating x and y but not able to understand wrt to parent how to get it and whether this x and y will give me pos wrt to parent

```
 position: Position = {x: 0, y: 0};

 @HostListener('dragStart', ['$event'])
 onDragStart(event: PointerEvent) {
   this.startPosition = {
    x: event.clientX - this.position.x,
    y: event.clientY - this.position.y
 }
 console.log("ondragstart")
 }

 @HostListener('dragMove', ['$event'])
  onDragMove(event: PointerEvent) {
   this.position.x = event.clientX - this.startPosition.x;
   this.position.y = event.clientY - this.startPosition.y;
 }
```

Comment: You can not subscribe to positional changes of DOM elements. Instead, you should be listening for the drag/drop events and handle changes then.

Comment: @Reactgular ok can I do somethingin this fashion [style.position.left]="item.position" and get the current position of the element and bind it

Comment: I have hostlistner in my directive   @HostListener('dragMove', ['$event'])
  onDragMove(event: PointerEvent) {
    this.position.x = event.clientX - this.startPosition.x;
    this.position.y = event.clientY - this.startPosition.y;
  }

Comment: @Reactgular , but on doing console inside ngonchanges for this.elm.toArray() gives me values but which one to pick I am not aware of, I want left and top position wrt to parent container, I'll add the screenshot

Comment: where do you set, `list`?

Comment: I am setting values to the list from @Input in ngonchanges, is that what you are asking

Comment: Hi, I have created a new issue for detectchanges error if you can help me with , the @Input existingDroppedItem gets new set of values everytime a new dropdown select has been made to be precise from parent component

Answer (score 1):

Your list index will be the same as your queryList index, so you should be able to do this. This makes use of the `Observable`, `changes` on the `QueryList`. This gets updated every time the DOM gets updated:

**template**

```
<div *ngFor="let itemPos of itemPositions$ | async;trackBy:trackByItem">
  {{ itemPos.item?.text }}
  {{ itemPos.element?.offsetTop }}
  {{ itemPos.element?.offsetLeft}}
</div>
```

**component**

```
@Input()
list: any[] = [];

@ViewChildren('elm') 
elm?: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLElement>>;

itemPositions$?: Observable<{ item: any, element: HTMLElement}[]>;

constructor(readonly cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.itemPositions$ = this.elm.changes.pipe(
    map(() => this.elementsToPositions()),
    tap(() => this.cd.detectChanges()),
    startWith(this.elementsToPositions()),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  this.cd.detectChanges();
}

elementsToPositions(): { item: any, element: HTMLElement}[] {
  return this.elm.toArray().map(({ nativeElement }, i) => ({
    item: this.list[i],
    element: nativeElement
  });
}

trackByItem = (i: number, itemPos: { item: any, element: HTMLElement}): string | number {
  // make sure every item has some unique ID, otherwise the `changes` will get 
  // called too often
  return itemPos.item.id || i;
}
```

Try to use the `ngOnChanges` hook as little as possible. If you do not use this properly it can get called way too much and will result in poor performance. Almost all cases you can solve in another, more descriptive way than `ngOnChanges`

Comment: thanks alot i'll try it out, so this will give me x and y position wrt the window(document)  if I am not wrong , it would be great if you could give your suggestions on how can I get the x and y positions wrt to immediate parent container

Comment: @Enthu I've updated my answer. You will have to use the `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` then on the element itself. Better would be to use a custom directive for this, and set the values from there using a HostListener, and then have your `ViewChildren` do a query on this directive, instead of using the nativeElement

Comment: Thankyou very much , I have added the custom directive code which I have for calculating the position ,how can I use this wrt to the particular element and display and also I have confusion whetehr the posiiton is wr tto the parent or to the window, thanks

Comment: hi, it gives me an error =  ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: null'. Current value: 'ngForOf: '.

Comment: Ah yes, because we set the observable inside the `ngAfterViewInit`, you need to do a `detectChanges`, or set the component to `OnPush` and set `markForCheck`

Comment: :) changedetectref or onpush please suggest :)

Comment: My suggestion is to put all components `OnPush` for performance reasons. Although this could break change detection functionality you depended on

Comment: I had placed this.cdr.detectChanges(); in the end inside ngAfterViewInit, it didin't throw any error in the beginning ,But didn't load the ngfor elements as well and when I started interacting with the component it threw same error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197872/discussion-between-enthu-and-pierreduc).

Comment: please have a look in the chat discussion

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`ngOnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) event. Because ngOnChanges triggered every changes.

```
ngOnChanges(){
   //Whatever you want
   this.list = .... ; 
   console.log(this.elm.toArray());
}
```

Comment: ok ngonchanges are not only for @input but for every change is it what you are suggesting ,could you please elaborate how can I access each of the element and display there respective positions if possible, thanks

Comment: I guess  ngonchanges helps but could you please help me in how can I display the value for the each of the indexes

Comment: Angular parameters binding two way. So, only write element whatever you want. What is latest value?

Comment: sorry still I am unable to understand how can I display on each div their respective top or left position, please elaborate, I'll try and if it works I can accept as it is partial answer, ngonchanges works but how do I display it

Comment: I have added console screenshot which I get by console.log(this.elm.toArray()); , now how can I get the values and display for each of the element