# Position DIV using Angular variable

Tags: css, angular

I have the following html:

```
<div class="absolute-position" [style.left]="title.box.x">{{title.box.x}}</div>
```

CSS:

```
.absolute-position {
    position: absolute;
}
```

title.box.x values:

```
0.5  300.5  600.5  899.5  1199.5
```

The problem is that all numbers are printed one on a top of the other on the left of the screen. If I change CCS to relative that it would like this:

[image]

How can I position DIVs horizontally using coordinates form Angular array?

Thanks

Comment: `[style.left.px]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - Jquery | Adding styles (top/left) with a mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372745/angular-2-jquery-adding-styles-top-left-with-a-mouse-position)

Comment: Yes, it does.  works like a charm.